# Use localized unit of appropriate magnitude in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, units-of-measurement

I'm using the new [Measurement API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/measurement) in iOS 10 to get a localized string for a length measurement:

```
let length = Measurement(value: 200, unit: UnitLength.centimeters)
let str = MeasurementFormatter().string(from: length)
```

However, for my (UK) locale, I then get back `"0.001 mi"`, which isn't a very helpful string to display. Instead, I'd prefer to get a string that used appropriate units (e.g. `"6.56 feet"` or `"2.19 yards"`) for the magnitude of the measurements. Is this possible with the API, or am I better off using a custom solution using SI prefixes?

Comment: You need to Se the unitOptiojs property of your formatter to .naturalScale https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/measurementformatter.unitoptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is straightforward:

```
let length = Measurement(value: 200, unit: UnitLength.centimeters)
let f = MeasurementFormatter()
f.unitOptions = MeasurementFormatter.UnitOptions.naturalScale
f.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2 
let str = MeasurementFormatter().string(from: length)
```